# JavaScript Object from any amount of inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and similar and I have a problem.
On my site, the user can create **any amount of inputs**. Now, Every newly added input group has 2 sides (name and value). I need to get those into a JavaScript **object**, just like that:

```
{
  "texture1" : "block/texture",
  "texture2" : "block/texture"
}
```

The input fields have the same names, so I can get them using `document.getElementsByName("textureName")` and `document.getElementsByName("textureValue")`.

I might be able to loop through the indexes of those objects (because they give the whole outerHTML-tag instead of their values), but I don't know how to do that correctly.

By the way, the HTML-code itself looks similar to that (just that users can insert any amount of that):

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="option">Name:<br><input name="textureName" value="particle"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="option">Value:<br><input name="textureValue" value="block/name"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers!
Anyway, I managed to find a solution myself, before I read your solutions:

```
var elementsCount = document.getElementsByName("name").length;
var textureName, textureValue, texturePair = {};
for (var i = 0; i<=elementsCount; i++) {
   textureName = document.getElementsByName("textureName")[i].value;
   textureValue = document.getElementsByName("textureValue")[i].value;
   texturePair[textureName] = textureValue;
   console.log(i);
   console.log(texturePair);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName` gives you a collection of element *objects*, not their `outerHTML`. Of those, the ones that are `HTMLInputElements` will have a `value` property which is the value of the input.

Since you're using parallel collections, you can build your object by looping over them as you've suggested, using the value of the "name" one for the name of the property and using the value of the "value" one for the value:

```
var names = documents.getElementsByName("textureName");
var values = documents.getElementsByName("textureValues");
if (names.length !== values.length) {
    // Something's wrong somewhere
}
var index;
var obj = {};
for (index = 0; index < names.length; ++index) {
    obj[names[index].value] = values[index].value;
}
```

That works because in JavaScript, you can access properties either using dot notation and a property name literal (`obj.foo`), or using brackets notation and a property name *string* (`obj["foo"]`). So in the above, we're using the latter.

---

While `getElementsByName` works and is perfectly appropriate for your use case, I'll just mention that you also have `querySelectorAll` available (on all modern browsers, and also IE8). That lets you select elements using any valid CSS selector, which lets you be more precise without adding extra marker attributes and classes and such to your HTML. Again, you probably don't need it here, but useful for future reference. `querySelectorAll` is available on `document`, and also on individual elements to search only within their descendants. There's also `querySelector` which, instead of returning a list, returns the first match (or `null` on no match).

Comment: As a tighter 'scope' you could also call `formElement.elements.namedItem('textureName')`, only thing to watch out for is it returns an array if multiple, but the DOM object if there's only one